# How to merge IUnityContainer with another IUnityContainer

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have a use case where my company moves from a legacy codebase to a new legacy codebase. The combination is unstable, merging the containers would help.

I identified a point where I want to merge the containers and pass a new container to the remaining application.

I have reason to believe that I can overwrite old types without causing problems.

How can I merge an `IUnityContainer` with another `IUnityContainer`?

The following is how far my experiments have taken me:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class ContainerUser
{
    public ContainerUser(IEnumerable<IUnityContainer> chaos)
    {
        IUnityContainer combined = new UnityContainer();
        //is there a highlevel method that can be used?
        //or is a foreach loop the way to go
        foreach (var uc in chaos)
        {
            foreach (var reg in uc.Registrations)
            {
                //combined.Register...???
                //usure what to so here
            }
        }
        //this throws unless combining the conainers works
        combined.Resolve<L1>().Exec();
        combined.Resolve<L2>().Exec();
    }
}

class L1
{
    private L1() { } //private so UnityContainer can not default construct
    public static L1 Get() { return new L1(); } //getter for InjectionFactory
    public void Exec() { Console.WriteLine("L1"); }
}

class L2
{
    private L2() { }
    public static L2 Get() { return new L2(); }
    public void Exec() { Console.WriteLine("L2"); }
}

class Program
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Randomize<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        //randomize to show i do not know a lot about my different containers
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return source.OrderBy<T, int>((item) => rnd.Next());
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //this is the setup, in my usecase these things happe behind the scenes and i can not influence them.
        var ucs = new List<IUnityContainer> { new UnityContainer(), new UnityContainer() };

        ucs[0].RegisterType<L1>(new InjectionFactory(c => L1.Get()));
        ucs[0].Resolve<L1>().Exec(); //proof L1 can resolve

        ucs[1].RegisterType<L2>(new InjectionFactory(c => L2.Get()));
        ucs[1].Resolve<L2>().Exec(); //proof L2 can resolve

        ContainerUser user = new ContainerUser(Randomize(ucs));
    }
}
```

Comment: It will likely involve writing a `UnityContainerExtension`, from inside there getting access to the [`ExtensionContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.extensioncontext(v=pandp.30).aspx) to get in to the internal structure of the established containers.

Comment: If the only thing you need is to resolve from a number of containers, then implementing your own `IUnityContainer` holding several containers maybe an option. The class you need to define should implement only the `Resolve` method, all other methods will just throw `NotImplementedException`. The `Resolve` method will try to resolve from each container and return the first resolved instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple approach how to use extensions to merge containers:

```
public class MergeContainerExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer[] containers;

    public MergeContainerExtension(params IUnityContainer[] containers)
    {
        this.containers = containers;
    }
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        foreach (var container in containers)
        {
            foreach (var registration in container.Registrations)
            {
                base.Container.
                    RegisterType(
                    registration.RegisteredType, 
                    registration.MappedToType,
                    registration.Name,
                    registration.LifetimeManager);
            }
        }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UnityContainer aContainer = new UnityContainer();
        UnityContainer bContainer = new UnityContainer();


        UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        MergeContainerExtension mergeExtension = new MergeContainerExtension(aContainer, bContainer);
        container.AddExtension(mergeExtension);


        var resolve = container.Resolve<IClassA>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working for Unity 5.11.1, seems like they changed a type for the LifetimeManager

Comment: Looks like you just need to cast it directly to ITypeLifetimeManager in order to get this working.